# get notified of login attemps using some sort of an api on linux

Tags: security, ssh, architecture, system, dbus

Currently i am using a tail -f mechanism to follow /var/log/auth.log and parse out sshd entries looking for specific behavior.

Does sshd have a C api?

Is there a more direct way to get notified, maybe via dbus, systemd?

Thanks

Comment: Try using PAM module... this link outlines a use case which triggers a web hook when someone does a login.

Comment: thanks, when i take a look a the /var/log/auth.log, it looks like the sshd process logs first and then pam logs afterwards for the same event. i googled a bit and was unable to find a pam C api which would allow me to listen to ssh related events in pam before it logs to /var/log/auth.log